# Maximum request length exceeded exception, maxContentLength not working

Tags: asp.net, iis

I know that this problem has a solution in stackoverflow, but it didn't work for me. I will be more specific below:

I had typical Maximum request length exceeded exception:

> HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found
>   The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

That's my changes to web.config, under system.web:

> ```
>   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="200000" executionTimeout="300" />
> ```

and under system.webServer:

> ```
>    <security>
>         <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="false">
>             <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="200000000" />
>         </requestFiltering>
>     </security>
> ```

I also made this changes in applicationHost.
On one machine these worked like charm. That was windows 7 + iis 7.5. But on another with windows server 2008 + iis 7.0 I cannot get upload of 19 MB to work. I really dont know what to do now. Please help anyone.

Comment: Have you tried checking whether you have Request Filtering installed as an IIS feature?

Comment: I don't have access to this machine now, but I assumed that Request Filtering is installed because there's Request Filtering option in IIS Manager. From there I set IIS maxContentAllowed option in "GUI" way. Also when I tried to uninstall this from Control Panel seconds ago, I cannot because ASP.NET depends on it.

Comment: Ah I see. Have you set the that Request Filtering value for your website/service, or the server as a whole? Have you also tried setting the maxRequestLength to 200000000?

Comment: I tried for server as whole in applicationHost.config file in windows file system. I also tried in web.config of my website of course. I even tried set maxRequestLength to 200000000, but then there is asp.net error that this value is out of maximum boundary (makes sense, because this is in KB according to MSDN).

Comment: Hmm, I am at the end of my knowledge now :/ I've never had an issue before with my own IIS set-ups regarding uploading. All I can recommend now is this article http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits, and I personally hate it when people link me an article :| so I apologise.

Comment: thanks for you interest anyway

Answer (score 0):

OK. That machine was client's machine. Apparently he changed something in IIS manager regarding one of the site's subfolders and IIS manager created web.config in subfolder that was overriding my setting in parent.